# How do I extract Windows XPSP3 dlls so that I can run the system file checker?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to repair corrupted system files using the system file checker. However I have an installation CD that is not recognized by the sfc utility when I insert it after being prompted. How do I extract the DLLs so that sfc will find them together with any other system files I would require?

Comment: The CD must be of the same service pack level the OS you are running SFC on, copying the wrong DLL's to a system can cause serious errors on reboot, use the correct CD.

Comment: What CD should I use? I installed SP3 from the Internet originally. I downloaded the SP3 upgrade iso to try and use that when prompted but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Propably a Live-CD can help you, have a look at : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs#Microsoft_Windows-based